# Software build validation tools?

Tags: github

Once a software build is generated either using Github of Gitlab, is there a way to validate the build candidate to make sure whether it is built with right files, commit id or git tag? I know unit and automation tests can be used to validate the changes integrated into the build, but I'm looking for a way to make sure before even starting Unit and Automation tests? Please let me know if you are using any such tool in your build infrastructure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why _not_ have such unit tests? You could likely order the tests such that those are run first, or you can group the tests in batches such that if one batch fails, it won't run future batches. It's down to your testing pipeline and architecture, but those kind of tests are for exactly this.

Comment: Yes, I like the idea, but my main goal of this question is to know whether there is any other way to validate the generated build, like either using Github actions workflow or not sure Maven --validate command can contribute to this use case. Thank you!

Comment: You can add whatever you want to your testing pipeline that you desire. But seeking general tools and software is off-topic for stackoverflow. In the end, what you'll have is some form of unit/automation test anyhow, just run in a separate suite/software/agent/build task/etc.